# How is the relation between $y$ and $x$ called in $y = 1/x$?

Tags: terminology

Probably a very simple question for most of you, but how is the relation called between $x$ and $y$ if $y = 1/x$?

As in, if I want to say: $y$ is .... related to $x$, what should go on the dots?

Update: Thank you all for your very quick responses! I was actually looking for the more general $y = c/x$, so the answer I was looking for seems to be "inversely proportional" (and not the more specific "reciprocal", even though that's perhaps a better answer for the $y = 1/x$ relation I mistakenly asked for)

Comment: it's an hyperbolic

Comment: The (multiplicative) inverse of $x$ is $y$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We say that they are inversely proportional.

Comment: it's a comment, not an answer !

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly the answer I was looking for!

Comment: @idm Can you think of any answer to this question which is not a comment?

Comment: @TyrCurtis You should expand on your comment. At least provide something more *substantial*. Just a moment ago someone asked what the value of $\int_1^e\frac{1}{x}\,dx$ was...I didn't just write $1$.

Comment: @induktio Feel free to edit my answer as you deem fit; I cannot think of a way to make it more substantial.

Comment: This is a complete answer to the question; I don't know why people are being so harsh to it. It's not like there's anything to add here that would be a natural extension of what is given. If someone feels this answer is insufficient they should surely write their own answer, rather than criticize a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: If you *really* want to flesh it out, you could add something like "Generally we say $y$ and $x$ are proportional if $\frac{x}{y}$ is a constant, and inversely proportional if $xy$ is a constant." But I agree, it's a perfectly good answer already.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the most appropriate term to fill in the dots left by Tiddo is *reciprocal*.

"$y$ is the reciprocal of $x$".

By looking at [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_inverse) in Wikipedia we learn that this comes from a XVI century translation of Euclid's *Elements*.

**PS**. I insist in this terminological vein since Tiddo seems to have said that this was the kind of answer he was expecting. @Tiddo, I suggest that you accept the answer that best suits your purposes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think I'm looking for inversely proportional though, if I understand the Wikipedia article correctly reciprocal is specific for `y = 1/x`, but for my intended purpose I'm actually looking for `y = c/x`. I'll update my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure you are looking for an answer like this: $y$ is inversely related to $x$[image]

To find the inverse, just switch $x$ and $y$ and solve for $y$.